# OSMDroid set click for CompassOverlay

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have Osmdroid map in my android application and need to set OnClickListener for the CompassOverlay. Actually, I need to set map orientation to the north when clicking on the compass.

How can I have this kind of functionality for the compass?

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question for others who have the same problem.

I extend CompassOverlay and create a new one with overriding onSingleTapConfirmed method.

```
class MyCompassOverlay : CompassOverlay {

    constructor(context: Context?, mapView: MapView) : super(context, mapView)

    constructor(context: Context?, iOrientationProvider: IOrientationProvider, mapView: MapView) : super(
        context,
        iOrientationProvider,
        mapView
    )

    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent?, mapView: MapView?): Boolean {
        mapView?.mapOrientation = 0f
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e, mapView)
    }

}
```

Note: It has a problem and it is by clicking on anywhere on the map it changes the orientation of the map (not only click on the compass).

Comment: Hi friend, did you get a solution for the problem of clicking on anywhere on the map it changes calls the event?

Comment: Hi, no not really, my requirements changed, so I didn't work on it more.